# Adding just one picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms

i need to add just one picturebox. But the code adds infinite pictureboxes. if my score is 10, i want to add just one picturebox. Pls help me to fix this:

```
if (score == 10)
{
    PictureBox zombie = new PictureBox();
    {

       zombie.Tag = "zombie"; // add a tag to it called zombie
       zombie.Image = Properties.Resources.beer_PNG2331; 
       zombie.Left = rnd.Next(0, 900); 
       zombie.Top = rnd.Next(0, 800); 
       zombie.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize; 
       this.Controls.Add(zombie); /
       player.BringToFront(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you used the extra bracers?

Comment: The method this code is in, how does it get called? Do you happen to call it on timer, on win32message or on a user input?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code - apart from the issue with the braces, but that doesn't cause the symptoms you are seeing.  The code must be getting called from many places, can you please add that information to this question?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: improving the answeer
remove the braces and make sure that there is no other part of your software that causes that part of code to be executed more than once with the same score value

```
if (score == 10)
{
    PictureBox zombie = new PictureBox();
    zombie.Tag = "zombie"; // add a tag to it called zombie
    zombie.Image = Properties.Resources.beer_PNG2331; 
    zombie.Left = rnd.Next(0, 900); 
    zombie.Top = rnd.Next(0, 800); 
    zombie.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize; 

    this.Controls.Add(zombie); 

    player.BringToFront(); 
}
```

Comment: "not your problem i think, but not needed" - so this does not answer the question? Then better write a comment instead of an answer. That said, the additional braces won't hurt. They are just redundant.

Comment: @Clemens yes, I saw that there was the semicolon so I edited and I did not revise, I edited the answer